# Binding Combobox items to an Access database with DataSet xsd

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-access

I'm trying to populate a combobox with items taken from an MS Access database in a `Dataset.xsd`:

[image]

Here's my code behind:

```
  private void GetData()
  {
        using (DB_TestDataSet dc = new DB_TestDataSet())
        {
            var query = from art in dc.FICHES_ARTICLES
                        where art.ART_SITE == 7
                        select new
                        {
                            art.ART_CODE,
                            art.ART_LIBELLE1
                        };
            Test_CB.ItemsSource = query;
            Test_CB.DisplayMemberPath = "ART_LIBELLE1";
            Test_CB.SelectedValuePath = "ART_CODE";
        }
 }

 public MainWindow()
 {
        InitializeComponent();
        GetData();
 }
```

Here's the connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Test_Access_App.Properties.Settings.DB_TestConnectionString"
         connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\DB_Test.mdb;Persist Security Info=True;Jet OLEDB:Database Password=1334"
         providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I get no errors but my combobox (`Test_CB`) stays empty. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Are you sure that query returns non empty data?

Comment: Yes.in my datable there are more thaï 200 rows

Comment: If this is ASP.NET web, you need to call `Test_CB.DataBind()` after setting the item source ...

Comment: Please add `wpf` tag to the question, you will get more responses then.

Comment: In data table maybe, but does query return any row?

Comment: When i test the query with "if(query.Any())" it returns false. This is strange...